# How do I change ADO ResultSet format in python?

Tags: python, ado

I have the following code to query a database using an ADO COMObject in python. This is connecting to a Time series database (OSIPI) and this is the only way we've been able to get Python connected to the database.

```
from win32com.client import Dispatch

oConn = Dispatch('ADODB.Connection')
oRS = Dispatch('ADODB.RecordSet')
oConn.ConnectionString = <my connection string>
oConn.Open()
oRS.ActiveConnection = oConn
if oConn.State == adStateOpen:
    print "Connected to DB"
else:
    raise SystemError('Database Connection Failed')

cmd = """SELECT tag, dataowner FROM pipoint WHERE tag LIKE 'TEST_TAG1%'"""  

self.oRS.Open(cmd)
result = oRS.GetRows(1) 
print result

result2 = oRS.GetRows(2)    
print result2

if oConn.State == adStateOpen: 
    oConn.Close()
oConn = None
```

This code returns the following two lines as results to the query:

```
result ((u'TEST_TAG1.QTY.BLACK',), (u'piadmin',))
result2 = ((u'TEST_TAG1.QTY.BLACK', u'TEST_TAG1.QTY.PINK'), (u'piadmin', u'piuser'))
```

This is not the expected format. In this case, I was expecting something like this:

```
result = ((u'TEST_TAG1.QTY.BLACK',u'piadmin'))
result2 = ((u'TEST_TAG1.QTY.BLACK',u'piadmin'), 
            (u'TEST_TAG1.QTY.PINK',u'piuser'))
```

Is there a way to adjust the results of an ADO query so everything related to row 1 is in the same tuple and everything in row 2 is in the same tuple?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you're seeing is not really a Python thing but the output of [GetRows()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms675120%28v=vs.85%29.aspx), which returns a two-dimensional array, which is organized by by field and then row.

Fortunately, Python has the [zip()](http://docs.python.org/library/functions.html#zip) function that will make the relevant change for you. Try changing your code from:

```
result = oRS.GetRows(1)
```

to:

```
result = zip(*oRS.GetRows(1))
```

etc.

Comment: This doesn't work. It changes it to: `[((u'TEST_TAG1.QTY.BLACK', u'TEST_TAG1.QTY.PINK'),), ((u'piadmin', u'piuser'),)]`

Comment: Try `zip(oRS.GetRows(1)[0])` or maybe `zip(*oRS.GetRows(1))`

Comment: `zip(*oRS.GetRows(1))` worked, if you want to edit the answer. Thank you.